# Bash - Regex for HTML contents

Tags: regex, bash

I'm learning about Bash scripting, and need some help understanding regex's.

I have a variable that is basically the html of a webpage (exported using wget):

```
currentURL = "https://www.example.com"
currentPage=$(wget -q -O - $currentURL)
```

I want to get the id's of all linked photos in this page. I just need help figuring out what the RegEx should be.

[I started with this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/167656), but I need to modify the regex:

Test string (this is what `currentURL` contains, there can be zero to many instances of this):

```
<a href="./download/file.php?id=123456&mode=view"><img src="./download/file.php?id=123456&t=1"></a>
```

Current Regex:

```
.\/download\/file.php\?id=[0-9]{6}\&mode=view
```

[Here's the regex I created](https://regex101.com/r/yE3tO8/105), but it doesn't seem to work in bash.

The best solution would be to have the ID of each file. In this case, simply `123456`. But if we can start with getting the `/download/file.php?id=123456`, that'd be a good start.

Comment: regex is not the right tool for such cases. xml/html parsers should be used. Post the actual testable url

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't parse XML/HTML with regex, use a proper XML/HTML parser.

#### theory :

According to the compiling theory, HTML can't be parsed using regex based on [finite state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). Due to hierarchical construction of HTML you need to use a [pushdown automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton) and manipulate [LALR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LR_parser) grammar using tool like [YACC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc).

#### realLife©®™ everyday tool in a [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) :

You can use one of the following :

[xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html) often installed by default with libxml2, xpath1

[xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/docs.php) can edit, select, transform... Not installed by default, xpath1

[xpath](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::XPath) installed via perl's module XML::XPath, xpath1

[xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html) xpath3

[saxon-lint](https://github.com/sputnick-dev/saxon-lint) my own project, wrapper over @Michael Kay's Saxon-HE Java library, xpath3

#### or you can use high level languages and proper libs, I think of :

[python](/questions/tagged/python)'s [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) (`from lxml import etree`)

[perl](/questions/tagged/perl)'s [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-LibXML/LibXML.pod), [`XML::XPath`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::XPath), [`XML::Twig::XPath`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig), [`HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath)

[php](/questions/tagged/php)'s [`DOMXpath`](https://sputnick.fr/scripts/parsing-HTML-with-DOMXpath.php.html)

---

Check: [Using regular expressions with HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

---

Example using [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel):

```
xidel -s "$currentURL" -e '//a/extract(@href,"id=(\d+)",1)'
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining why a RegEx is not suitable for parsing HTML. I'll try this out.

Comment: I tried this out but could not get it to work. How do I feed the contents of `currentURL` into this?

Comment: Xidel can do this all by itself without the need of grep or sed: `./xidel -s "$currentURL" -e '//a/extract(@href,"id=(\d+)",1)'`

Comment: Thanks @Reino, added it to my post. I start learning xidel even if I know it since a couple of years

Comment: @Reino: do you have doc on this syntax? `'//a/extract(@href,"id=(\d+)",1)'`

Comment: For [`extract()`](https://www.benibela.de/documentation/internettools/xpath-functions.html#x-extract) you mean?

Comment: Thanks. And the use of `1` ? This is more like `grep -oP`, you should correct your doc. Very nice trick

Comment: OK: `If the $match argument is provided, only the $match-th submatch will be returned.`

Comment: I'm not `xidel`'s author, @BeniBela is. If you're correct, then _he_ should fix that. Btw, if you want to learn more about all the things you can do with `xidel`, then you might find [my hobby-project](https://github.com/Reino17/xivid/) interesting (the XQuery Module _'xivid.xqm'_ in particular). Beware that the documentation is in Dutch.

Comment: https://github.com/benibela/xidel/issues/101

Answer (score 4):

Let's first clarify a couple of misunderstandings.

> I'm learning about Bash scripting, and need some help understanding regex's.

You seem to be implying some sort of relation between Bash and regex.
As if Bash was some sort of regex engine.
It isn't. The `[[` builtin is the only thing I recall in Bash that supports regular expressions, but I think you mean something else.

There are some common commands executed in Bash that support some implementation of regular expressions such as `grep` or `sed` and others. Maybe that's what you meant. It's good to be specific and accurate.

> I want to get the id's of all linked photos in this page. I just need help figuring out what the RegEx should be.

This suggests an underlying assumption that if you want to extract content from an HTML, then regex is the way to go. [That assumption is incorrect.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

---

Although it's best to extract content from HTML using an XML parser (using one of the suggestions in Gilles' answer),
and trying to use regex for it is not a good reflect,
for simple cases like yours it might just be good enough:

```
grep -oP '\./download/file\.php\?id=\K\d+(?=&mode=view)' file.html
```

Take note that you escaped the wrong characters in the regex:

- `/` and `&` don't have a special meaning and don't need to be escaped
- `.` and `?` have special meaning and need to be escaped

Some extra tricks in the above regex are good to explain:

- The `-P` flag of `grep` enables Perl style (powerful) regular expressions
- `\K` is a Perl specific symbol, it means to not include in the match the content before the `\K`
- The `(?=...)` is a zero-width positive lookahead assertion. For example, `/\w+(?=\t)/` matches a word followed by a tab, without including the tab in the match.
- The `\K` and the lookahead trickery is to work with `grep -o`, which outputs only the matched part. But without these trickeries the matched part would be for example `./download/file.php?id=123456&mode=view`, which is more than what you want.

Comment: *As if Bash was some sort of regex engine. It isn't.* While I agree with what you are saying, to be accurate, Bash does implement ERE regex substantially similar to POSIX grep. ERE regex is still not suitable for parsing HTML.