# replace tag content in xml file using sed command

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

I want to replace  the "value" tag  after the "name" tag with **false** using `sed` command. I've tried multiple things without success. There is a lot of "value" tags in my file so i think that i should use this tag `<name>hive.metastore.schema.verification</name>` in regex`

```
<property>
    <name>hive.metastore.schema.verification</name>
    <value>true</value>
    <description>
    foobar 
    </description>
</property>
```

This is my command :

```
sed '/<property>/!b;:a;/<\/property>/!{$!{N;ba}};/hive.metastore.schema.verification</s/.*\n/&<value>false<\/value>\n/' hive-site.xml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### With the good tool, using [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath):

```
xmlstarlet edit -L \
    -u '/property[./name/text() = "hive.metastore.schema.verification"]/value' \
    -v false file.xml
```

[Don't use `sed` nor `regex` to parse `XML`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49352373/465183)

Comment: xmlstarlet  can't update the content of my file. It print the contenf of file in my terminal.  There might be something missing in your command.

Comment: Added `-L` to edit in-place... Like `sed -i` does

Comment: the same thing  <value>true</value> .

Comment: this is my file  https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/data/conf/hive-site.xml . i want to replace true by false in the line 96

Comment: You have now more than a clue to do the work yourself. As a start, check `xmlstarlet edit --help`

Comment: Your sample works with my command. If it don't work, your sample should be more accurate. https://hastebin.com/share/malibuwifa.xml