# Remove Block of HTML Table Data Linux Bash

Tags: html, linux, bash, sed

I have a html file that I process using a bash script and want to remove empty tables.  The file is generated from a sql statement, but contains the table header when no records are found.  I want to remove the header where no records are found.

```
<table border="1">
  <caption>Table with data</caption>
  <tr>
    <th align="center">type</th>
    <th align="center">column1</th>
    <th align="center">column2</th>
    <th align="center">column3</th>
    <th align="center">column4</th>
   </tr>
   
   Data rows exists here
   
  </table>

<table border="1">
  <caption>Empty Table To Remove</caption>
  <tr>
    <th align="center">type</th>
    <th align="center">column1</th>
    <th align="center">column2</th>
    <th align="center">column3</th>
    <th align="center">column4</th>
    <th align="center">column5</th>
    <th align="center">column6</th>
    <th align="center">column7</th>
  </tr>
</table>

<table border="1">
  <caption>Table with data</caption>
  <tr>
   <th align="center">type</th>
    <th align="center">column1</th>
    <th align="center">column2</th>
    <th align="center">column3</th>
    <th align="center">column4</th>
   </tr>
     Data rows exists here
  </table>
```

I tried to use a combination of grep and sed to remove the empty table.  I was able to accomplish this when the tables contained an equal number of columns.  I am having issues now that I have tables with a different number of columns.

When the table had an equal number of columns, I was able to loop through based on the caption, do a count and then remove.  This is not working since the number of columns vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this, using [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet) and [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath):

```
$ xmlstarlet format -H file.html | sponge file.html
$ xmlstarlet ed -d '//table[./caption/text()="Empty Table To Remove"]' file.html 
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <body>
    <table border="1"><caption>Table with data</caption><tr><th align="center">type</th><th align="center">column1</th><th align="center">column2</th><th align="center">column3</th><th align="center">column4</th></tr>
   
   Data rows exists here
   
  </table>
    <table border="1"><caption>Table with data</caption><tr><th align="center">type</th><th align="center">column1</th><th align="center">column2</th><th align="center">column3</th><th align="center">column4</th></tr>
     Data rows exists here
  </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

To edit in place like `sed -i`, use

```
xmlstarlet edit -L ...
```

Not explained, but [don't use `sed` nor `regex` to parse `HTML/XML`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49352373/465183)

Comment: This is really good!  I can make this work.  Pretty versatile utility.