# replace xml value in shell

Tags: xml, shell, sed, xml-namespaces

I want to replace a value in XML file with sed:
here is the origin line:

```
<ns3:myID>aaa:bb:cc:dd::123-sd3-7b</ns3:myID>
```

I want to replace the values between `<ns3:myID>` and `</ns3:myID>`.

I tried

```
sed -Ei - "s/(myID\>).*(<.*)$/\1${MY_NEW_VALUE}\2/" path.xml
```

it does replace the value, but it generates a new temp file which is not acceptable, can someone know a sed command line that can in-place replace the above value without generating any temp files?

Comment: Show us your XML input.

Comment: [Don't use `sed` nor `regex` to parse `XML`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49352373/465183)  you cannot, must not parse any structured text like XML/HTML with tools designed to process raw text lines. If you need to process XML/HTML, use an XML/HTML parser. A great majority of languages have built-in support for parsing XML and there are dedicated tools like XMLStarlet if you need a quick shot from a command line shell. Never accept a job if you don't have access to proper tools.

Comment: Can you try removing the `hyphen` after the `-Ei` ?

Comment: I tried but got an error.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
xmlstarlet edit -L -N ns3='<NAMESPACE URL>' -u '//ns3:myID' -v NEW_VALUE file.xml
```

- `-L` is equivalent to the `-i` of `sed`
- the namespace URL is what is after `xmlns:ns3` in your `xml` file.

Answer (score 0):

Some implementations need an extension for `-i` (case for [FreeBSD](https://nixdoc.net/man-pages/FreeBSD/man1/sed.1.html) and MacOS, but not for [OpenBSD](https://man.openbsd.org/sed) and GNU/Linux.) This non standard option may also have some [subtle meaning](https://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/1/sed/). You should really check the documentation of the `sed` command you're using and be aware of portability issue of your script (if using it via a script)