# Match groups between tags over multiple lines via regex

Tags: regex, character-class

I want to match groups between opening and ending tags in a multiline text via regular expression.

I know that this question has been asked a lot before here in this community...
Unfortunately, I am facing some restrictions of my regex parser in this way that I cannot use whole language support of regular expression.
For example, it is not possible to use shortcuts like `\s` or `\S` :(...

Example source:

```
<html>
  <p>
   Line 1
   Line 2
   Line 3
  </p>
</html>
```

The following regex would work perfectly: `(<p>[\s|\S]+</p>)`.

As I mentioned before, I am not able to use shortcuts like `\s` or `\S`.
Therefore I tried to rewrite the regex by using character classes like `[:space:]`.

And that's the point I don't understand what's happening.
If I simply replace the `\s` and `\S` by `[[:space:]]` and `[^[:space:]]` the regex does not work anymore...
`(<p>[[^[:space:]]|[[:space:]]]+</p>)`

Can anyone help me out here?

BR
Steve

Comment: [Don't use `sed` nor `regex` to parse `XML`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49352373/465183) you cannot, must not parse any structured text like XML/HTML with tools designed to process raw text lines. If you need to process XML/HTML, use an XML/HTML parser. A great majority of languages have built-in support for parsing XML and there are dedicated tools like XMLStarlet if you need a quick shot from a command line shell. Never accept a job if you don't have access to proper tools.

Comment: Agree with @GillesQuénot. However, in this very simple case [\s|\S] is equivalent to . (a dot). \s is whitespace, \S is non whitespace. Their union is all characters, ie . (dot), so (<p>.+</p>)

Comment: For your case abandon the \s\S stuff, and just use (.|\n).  I used `<(p)[^>]*>(?:.|\n)*?<\/\1>`, a little fancier.  Remember that <p can have attributes, so `[^>]*` gets you beyond them.  But ultimately @Gilles is right; all you need is some embedded string with some math containing "p>25", or some sub-docs with more <p>'s to completely throw you off.

Answer (score 0):

You might have some extra brackets there.

This seems to work.

```
<p>(([^[:space:]]|[[:space:]])+?)</p>
```

https://regex101.com/r/D9pydg/1

where group 1 gets the *lines*.