# Match first hit only in a XML with grep

Tags: xml, shell, unix, grep

Say I have the below simplified type of XML file and need to extract all of the string data that is within the `<innerElement>` and `</innerElement>` tags only for the Id 1234.

```
<outerTag>
  <innerElement>
    <Id>1234</Id>
    <fName>Kim</fName>
    <lName>Scott</lName>
<customData1>Value1</customData1>
<customData2>Value2</customData2>
    <position>North</position>
    <title/>
  </innerElement>
  <innerElement>
    <Id>5678</Id>
    <fName>Brian</fName>
    <lName>Davis</lName>
<customData3>value3</customData3>
<customData4>value4</customData4>
<customData5>value5</customData5>
    <position>South</position>
    <title/>
  </innerElement>
</outerTag>
```

My expected output is:

```
<innerElement>
    <Id>1234</Id>
    <fName>Kim</fName>
    <lName>Scott</lName>
<customData1>Value1</customData1>
<customData2>Value2</customData2>
    <position>North</position>
    <title/>
</innerElement>
```

Using what I have read on other posts I have tried using grep -z to match multiline strings (treating the file contents as a single line) and -o to print only exact matches, but when I use the .* wildcard after the Id element it ends matching everything up to the end of the file instead of stopping on the fist occurrence.

`grep -zo '<innerElement>.*<Id>1234</Id>.*</innerElement>' myfile.xml`

How can I make the pattern match up to only the fist occurrence or the  tag after Id 1234?

Comment: Please [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858) I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: @Cyrus thanks, read the post, didn't know about the craziness of using regex for XML/html parsing. Will get through those parsers instead.

Comment: Avoid modifying the input file without any communication when you get answers, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Don't use `sed` nor `regex` to parse `XML`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49352373/465183) you cannot, must not parse any structured text like XML/HTML with tools designed to process raw text lines. If you need to process XML/HTML, use an XML/HTML parser. A great majority of languages have built-in support for parsing XML and there are dedicated tools like `xidel`, `xmlstarlet` or `xmllint` if you need a quick shot from a command line shell.

### With a proper `XML` parser

##### Using `xidel`

```
xidel --xml -e '//innerElement[Id="1234"]' file.xml
```

##### Using `xmlstarlet`

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -c '//innerElement[Id="1234"]' file.xml
```

##### Using `xmllint`

```
xmllint --xpath '//innerElement[Id="1234"]' file.xml
```

##### Output

```
<innerElement>
    <Id>1234</Id>
    <fName>Kim</fName>
    <lName>Scott</lName>
    <customData1>Value1</customData1>
    <customData2>Value2</customData2>
    <position>North<position><title/></position>
  </position>
  </innerElement>
```

Comment: Indeed `xmlstarlet` is the right rool

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your approach to this issue. Your query (or rather queries) do not produce that particular output. And why would you edit XML-file instead of just extracting what's needed? `xidel -s file.xml -e '//innerElement[Id="1234"]' --output-node-format=xml --output-node-indent`

Comment: Because I had the nested node with my attempts for whatever reason.

Comment: **xmlstarlet** worked like a charm for me. I needed to extract only certain nodes based on their IDs from an xml file and place them on another. I used this line --->    `xmlstarlet sel -t -c '//innerElement[./Id[text()='1234']]' inputFile.xml >> outputFile.xml`

Comment: You can use `xmlstarlet edit --help` to move nodes