# How to match text in quotation marks between p tags (regex) - Calibre Search and Replace

Tags: html, regex, calibre

I need to do some formatting on the text below and to do so I need to match only the text between quotes inside p tags (<p> and </p>).

This text below is an example:

```
<div class="vung_doc" id="vung_doc">
<p>Volume 1: The Mysterious Driver
</p>
<p>He picked up the pistol from the pool of blood and pointed it at the
person coming towards him, screaming, "I'll kill you!"
</p>
<p>No matter how many times he pressed the trigger, the rounds didn't budge.
The approaching figure mockingly spoke, "Haha, what a scene! The Great Detective Song Lang, 
actually killing his superior and partner with his very own hands! I can't wait to see the 
headlines in the newspapers tomorrow!"
</p>
```

I need only to match `"I'll kill you!"` and `"Haha, what a scene! The Great Detective Song Lang, actually killing his superior and partner with his very own hands! I can't wait to see the headlines in the newspapers tomorrow!"`

But most of the regex I tried got all the text between quotes `*"(.\*?)"*`, all the text between the p tags `*\<p\>(.|\\n)\*?\<\\/p\>*` or something in between.

**I use Calibre search and replace, so only one line of regex.** I use [ReExr](https://regexr.com/) to test the expressions.

Comment: Regex are nor the right tool, use an HTML/XML parser

Answer (score 1):

##### [Don't use `regex` to parse `HTML`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49352373/465183)

you cannot, must not parse any structured text like XML/HTML with tools designed to process raw text lines. If you need to process XML/HTML, use an XML/HTML parser. A great majority of languages have built-in support for parsing XML and there are dedicated tools like `xidel`, `xmlstarlet` or `xmllint` if you need a quick shot from a command line shell.

##### With `xidel`:

```
xidel -e '//p/extract(text(),"&quot;(.+)&quot;",1,"s")[.]' file
```

Credits to Reino.

##### With `xidel` and `grep`:

```
xidel -e '//p' file | grep -oP '"\K[^"]+' file
```

##### Output

```
I'll kill you!
Haha, what a scene! The Great Detective Song Lang, actually killing his superior and partner with his very own hands! I can't wait to see the headlines in the newspapers tomorrow!
```

Here, I use `grep` `regex` only on the *text part*.

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Already linked in the link in my answer

Comment: Or solely with `xidel`: `-e '//p/extract(text(),"&quot;(.+)&quot;",1,"s")[.]'`

Comment: Looks sufficient: `-e '//p/extract(text(),"&quot;(.*)&quot;",1,"s")'`

Comment: That will output an empty line, because the first `<p>` element-node doesn't have a text-node with double-quotes in it. Hence the `[.]` to discard non-matches.