# Regex to transform link tag to img tag

Tags: html, regex, dom

I need a regex to find all the occurrences ( could be multiple ) of an  tag with the text: "Graphic source" and transform it to an img tag with the src attribute that contains the href url.

So FROM

```
<small><a href="https://www.url.com/image.png" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Graphic source</a></small>
```

TO

```
<img src="https://www.url.com/image.png"/>
```

So for example:

```
Some text
Other tag <b>test</b>
<small><a href="https://www.url.com/name1.png" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Graphic source</a></small>test
<small><a href="https://www.url.com/name2.jpg" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Graphic source</a></small>Text text<small><a href="www.url.com">Do not transform</a></small>
```

Needs to be transformed as:

```
Some text
Other tag <b>test</b>
<img src="https://www.url.com/name1.png"/>test
<img src="https://www.url.com/name2.jpg"/>Text text<small><a href="www.url.com">Do not transform</a></small>
```

I almost got it working:
`<small.*?href="(.*?)"`

I don't understand how to NOT include the a tag that do not contains the words Graphic source as text and how to NOT include all the other attributes of the a tag when transformed to img tag.

https://regex101.com/r/OReOCd/1

Comment: This is a task for a language like Python, Perl, Javascript, Ruby, Java, Groovy, PHP with a real HTML parser. Never use regex to parse HTML. If you have regex and html in the same question, you are not in the right direction.

Comment: Gilles is correct. You need a proper parser, I speak from hard-learned experience. There's a famous SO answer regarding Regex and HTML, I regret I couldn't find it.

Comment: Please tag your question with the programming language you are using so that non-regex solutions can be offered.

Comment: Advice to newcomers: If an answer solves your problem, please accept it by clicking the large check mark (✓) next to it and optionally also up-vote it (up-voting requires at least 15 reputation points). If you found other answers helpful, please up-vote them. Accepting and up-voting helps future readers. See [the relevant help-center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

#### Don't use `regex` to parse `HTML/XML`

Check:

- Jeff Atwood's blog, co-founder of stackoverflow:

  - https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/
- One of the most famous page here:

  - [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)
- My explanations:

  - https://stackoverflow.com/a/49352373/465183

Better use a programming language and proper libraries to parse `HTML`.

#### With one of the most used language, Python:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

res = requests.get('https://sputnick.fr/downloads/regex-to-transform-link-tag-to-img-tag.html')
tree = html.fromstring(res.text)
    
# Using proper XPath query language:
elts = tree.xpath('//a[text()="Graphic source"]')

for a_elt in elts:
    img_elt = html.Element("img", src=a_elt.get("href"))
    a_elt.getparent().replace(a_elt, img_elt)

transformed_html = html.tostring(tree, encoding="unicode")

print(transformed_html)
```

#### Or PHP, using [`DOMXPath`](https://www.php.net/DOMXPath):

```
<?php
    $html = file_get_contents('https://sputnick.fr/downloads/regex-to-transform-link-tag-to-img-tag.html');
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    
    // Using proper XPath query language:
    $elements = $xpath->query('//a[text()="Graphic source"]');
    
    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        $href = $element->getAttribute('href');
        $imgElement = $dom->createElement('img');
        $imgElement->setAttribute('src', $href);
        $element->parentNode->replaceChild($imgElement, $element);
    }
    
    $transformedHtml = $dom->saveHTML();
    
    echo $transformedHtml;
?>
```

#### Output

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
  </head>
  <body>
Some text
Other tag <b>test</b>
<small><img src="https://www.url.com/name1.png"></small>test
<small><img src="https://www.url.com/name2.jpg"></small>Text text<small><a href="www.url.com">Do not transform</a></small>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

> "... I need a regex to find all the occurrences ... and transform [them] to an img tag with the src attribute that contains the href url. ..."

The regex pattern itself won't replace any values, it simply matches.
You'll need to use a program or programming language.

> *"... I don't understand how to NOT include the a tag that do not contains the words Graphic source as text ..."*

Assert that the text following the `>` is *"Graphic source<"*

```
<.+?href\s*=\s*("|')(.+?)(?<!\\)\1.+?>Graphic source<.+>
```

The substitution text would be,

```
<img src="$2"/>
```

Also, I presume you could use `\s*` preceding and following the text.

```
<.+?href\s*=\s*("|')(.+?)(?<!\\)\1.+?>\s*Graphic source\s*<.+>
```

> *"... and how to NOT include all the other attributes of the a tag when transformed to img tag. ..."*

In this type of situation, where there are repeated keys and values, you can use the *lazy-quantifier*, `?`, to match up to the first encountered quotation-mark.

For example,

```
=\"(.+?)\"
```

Here is an example output

```
Some text
Other tag <b>test</b>
<img src="https://www.url.com/name1.png"/>test
<img src="https://www.url.com/name2.jpg"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Obligatory disclaimer: [Stop Parsing (X)HTML with Regular Expression](https://medium.com/thecyberfibre/stop-parsing-x-html-with-regular-expression-2cf13215b411)

```
<small><a href="(.*?)"[^>]*?>Graphic source<\/a><\/small>
```

https://regex101.com/r/2Wd9le/1