# Editing XML file using macro on Excel 2019

Tags: excel, xml, vba

Hope you are all doing great!

I am try to edit bunch of XML files that are generated by my CNC machine.

All I want to do is, if <CUT> before <NUM>*</NUM> (* being variable INT) anywhere then it have to replace the value to a number that I have on my table. The table consist of the Item tag and the QTY (QTY value will be the replacement of * and the Item Tag will be the name of XML file)

I tried creating macro, just to replace <NUM>*</NUM> to <NUM>1</NUM> to begin with, but that's not working at all. Tried using CHATGPT to find solution. Below is the macro generated. Attached is the example of the file

```
Sub EditXMLFile()
    Dim SourceFile As String
    Dim DestFolder As String
    Dim FileDialog As FileDialog
    Dim XMLDoc As Object
    Dim TextToReplace As String
    Dim NewText As String
    
    ' Prompt user to select the XML file
    Set FileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    FileDialog.Title = "Select the XML file to edit"
    FileDialog.Filters.Clear
    FileDialog.Filters.Add "XML Files", "*.xml"
    
    If FileDialog.Show = -1 Then
        SourceFile = FileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Prompt user for destination folder
    Set FileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    If FileDialog.Show = -1 Then
        DestFolder = FileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Load the selected XML file
    Set XMLDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
    XMLDoc.async = False
    XMLDoc.Load SourceFile
    
    ' Define the text to replace and the new text
    TextToReplace = "<NUM>*</NUM>"
    NewText = "<NUM>1</NUM>"
    
    ' Start the recursive search and replace
    ReplaceTextRecursively XMLDoc, TextToReplace, NewText
    
    ' Save the modified XML file to the destination folder
    XMLDoc.Save DestFolder & "\" & "ModifiedXML.xml"
    
    ' Clean up
    Set XMLDoc = Nothing
    Set FileDialog = Nothing
    
    MsgBox "XML file edited and saved successfully!", vbInformation
End Sub

Sub ReplaceTextRecursively(ByRef Node As Object, ByVal TextToReplace As String, ByVal NewText As String)
    Dim ChildNode As Object
    
    If Node Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    If Node.HasChildNodes Then
        For Each ChildNode In Node.ChildNodes
            ReplaceTextRecursively ChildNode, TextToReplace, NewText
        Next ChildNode
    End If
    
    If Node.NodeType = 3 Then ' Text node
        If InStr(Node.Text, "<CUT>") > 0 Then
            Node.Text = Replace(Node.Text, TextToReplace, NewText)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

---

The CODE inside XML file that need to edited(I wish to attach the file)

```
<JOB>
    <JINF>
        <NUM>0</NUM>
    </JINF>
    <BODY>
        <BAR>
            <BRAN>TESTENVIRONMENT</BRAN>
            <SYST>7000 SERIES</SYST>
            <CODE>70-110_938</CODE>
            <DESC>
            </DESC>
            <DICL>
            </DICL>
            <DOCL>
            </DOCL>
            <LEN>0</LEN>
            <LENR>0</LENR>
            <H>146.5</H>
            <MLT>-1</MLT>
            <POS>0</POS>
            <ICL>
            </ICL>
            <OCL>
            </OCL>
            <SCRI>0</SCRI>
            <SCRF>0</SCRF>
            <LREUSAB>0</LREUSAB>
            <SCRP>0</SCRP>
            <CTIM>0</CTIM>
            <CTSP>0</CTSP>
            <SVL>0</SVL>
            <IVL>0</IVL>
            <VROT>0</VROT>
            <VU1S>0</VU1S>
            <VU1D>0</VU1D>
            <VU2S>0</VU2S>
            <VU2D>0</VU2D>
            <SCP>0</SCP>
            <BRS>0</BRS>
            <IFS>0</IFS>
            <BS1L>0</BS1L>
            <BS1R>0</BS1R>
            <BS2L>0</BS2L>
            <BS2R>0</BS2R>
            <PRPZ>0</PRPZ>
            <PRMA>0</PRMA>
            <PRMB>0</PRMB>
            <PRMO>0</PRMO>
            <PRMV>0</PRMV>
            <STMV>0</STMV>
            <MXBN>0</MXBN>
            <W>85</W>
            <ENTH>0</ENTH>
            <COLOR a="255" r="128" g="128" b="128"/>
            <DXF>
            </DXF>
            <REV>0</REV>
            <INNESTABILE>0</INNESTABILE>
            <NUM>1</NUM>
            <PRIORITA>0</PRIORITA>
            <STATOBARRA>0</STATOBARRA>
            <STATOCONGELATO>0</STATOCONGELATO>
            <MODELLO_CON_ERRORI>0</MODELLO_CON_ERRORI>
            <ID_ESTERNO>
            </ID_ESTERNO>
            <OFFESET_X>0</OFFESET_X>
            <OFFESET_Y>0</OFFESET_Y>
            <OFFESET_Z>0</OFFESET_Z>
            <OFFESET_YCLOSE>0</OFFESET_YCLOSE>
            <VIRTPLATE>
            </VIRTPLATE>
            <CUT>**<NUM>123</NUM>
**<NUMEXE>0</NUMEXE>
                <TINA>
                </TINA>
                <ANGL>90</ANGL>
                <ANGR>90</ANGR>
                <AB1>90</AB1>
                <AB2>90</AB2>
                <IL>1396.16998</IL>
                <OL>1396.16998</OL>
                <TRML>0</TRML>
                <TL1>0</TL1>
                <TAL>90</TAL>
                <TRMR>0</TRMR>
                <TL2>0</TL2>
                <TAR>90</TAR>
                <TLON>0</TLON>
                <TRON>0</TRON>
                <TLMTON>0</TLMTON>
                <TRMTON>0</TRMTON>
                <MARGIN1>0</MARGIN1>
                <MARGIN2>0</MARGIN2>
                <BCOD>938%70110.IN1E.0008-1396</BCOD>
                <EXTERNAL_ID>0</EXTERNAL_ID>
                <CSNA>
                </CSNA>
                <CSNU>
                </CSNU>
                <ORCD>70110.IN1E.0008-1396</ORCD>
                <ORDCDQTY>1</ORDCDQTY>
                <DESC>
                </DESC>
                <CID>
                </CID>
                <IDQUADRO>
                </IDQUADRO>
                <FRNU>
                </FRNU>
                <STAT>0</STAT>
                <SUBAREA_BARRA>0</SUBAREA_BARRA>
                <PEZZO_RIFATTO>0</PEZZO_RIFATTO>
                <RT>
                    <Vx x="1" y="0" z="0"/>
                    <Vy x="0" y="1" z="0"/>
                    <T x="0" y="0" z="0"/>
                </RT>
                <AREA>0</AREA>
                <STOP>0</STOP>
                <PRINT_LABEL>1</PRINT_LABEL>
                <LBL>
                </LBL>
                <LBL>938%70110.IN1E.0008-1396</LBL>
                <LBL>
                </LBL>
                <LBL>LAVORARE</LBL>
                <MACHININGS>
                    <MACHINING WCODE="#0" OFFSET="1296.17" OFFSETY="127.5"
                               OFFSETZ="-3.15" FORMULAX="" FORMULAY=""
                               FORMULAZ="" FACE="2" TIPOLAV="" VAR1="5.5"
                               VAR2="" VAR3="" VAR4="" VAR5="" ANGLE="0"
                               VERPERC="1" P1X="0" P1Y="0" P1Z="0" P2X="0"
                               P2Y="0" P2Z="0" P3X="0" P3Y="0" P3Z="0"
                               INVERSEPATHONMULTIPLANES="0" EMPTYGROVE="0"
                               BREAKSHAVING="0" CODUTENSILE="35" CILINLAV="2"
                               OFFSETFIN="0" CODUTEFIN="0" CILLAVFIN="0"
                               DESCRIPTION="Drill D11.000" SGRAVANZ="0"
                               SGRUSCITA="0" SRGLAV="0" SGRROT="0"
                               VARPROFSGR="0" FINAVANZ="0" FINUSCITA="0"
                               FINLAV="0" FINROT="0" VARPROFFIN="0"
                               EXECUTIONLEVEL="1" IDCATEGORY="1" POSDEF=""
                               ENABLELOAD="" IDMACHINING="0" CLAMPNEAR="0"
                               STARTCONNECTION="0" ENDCONNECTION="0"
                               TIPOSTAZIONE="Lavorazione" STATION_ID=""
                               NUMEROSOTTOLAVORAZIONI="1"
                               NUMEROFORIANUBATRICE="0" NUMEROANUBATURE="0"
                               SGRTIPO="2" FINTIPO="0" STATION_EXTRA_DATA="10">
                        <FORBIDDENSPACES/>
                        <PIANI>
                            <PIANO START="0" THICK="10" AVANZAMENTO="0"
                                   ROTAZIONE="0"/>
                            <PIANO START="10" THICK="1.40822017993"
                                   AVANZAMENTO="0" ROTAZIONE="0"/>
                            <PIANO START="11.40822017993" THICK="0.013086202792"
                                   AVANZAMENTO="0" ROTAZIONE="0"/>
                        </PIANI>
                    </MACHINING>
                    <MACHINING WCODE="#0" OFFSET="100" OFFSETY="127.5"
                               OFFSETZ="-3.15" FORMULAX="" FORMULAY=""
                               FORMULAZ="" FACE="2" TIPOLAV="" VAR1="5.5"
                               VAR2="" VAR3="" VAR4="" VAR5="" ANGLE="0"
                               VERPERC="1" P1X="0" P1Y="0" P1Z="0" P2X="0"
                               P2Y="0" P2Z="0" P3X="0" P3Y="0" P3Z="0"
                               INVERSEPATHONMULTIPLANES="0" EMPTYGROVE="0"
                               BREAKSHAVING="0" CODUTENSILE="35" CILINLAV="2"
                               OFFSETFIN="0" CODUTEFIN="0" CILLAVFIN="0"
                               DESCRIPTION="Drill D11.000" SGRAVANZ="0"
                               SGRUSCITA="0" SRGLAV="0" SGRROT="0"
                               VARPROFSGR="0" FINAVANZ="0" FINUSCITA="0"
                               FINLAV="0" FINROT="0" VARPROFFIN="0"
                               EXECUTIONLEVEL="1" IDCATEGORY="2" POSDEF=""
                               ENABLELOAD="" IDMACHINING="0" CLAMPNEAR="0"
                               STARTCONNECTION="0" ENDCONNECTION="0"
                               TIPOSTAZIONE="Lavorazione" STATION_ID=""
                               NUMEROSOTTOLAVORAZIONI="1"
                               NUMEROFORIANUBATRICE="0" NUMEROANUBATURE="0"
                               SGRTIPO="2" FINTIPO="0" STATION_EXTRA_DATA="10">
                        <FORBIDDENSPACES/>
                        <PIANI>
                            <PIANO START="0" THICK="10" AVANZAMENTO="0"
                                   ROTAZIONE="0"/>
                            <PIANO START="10" THICK="1.408220179937"
                                   AVANZAMENTO="0" ROTAZIONE="0"/>
                            <PIANO START="11.408220179937"
                                   THICK="0.013086202769" AVANZAMENTO="0"
                                   ROTAZIONE="0"/>
                        </PIANI>
                    </MACHINING>
                </MACHININGS>
            </CUT>
            <AREE_ROVINATE/>
            <TIMES/>
            <TEMPI_CN_START>
            </TEMPI_CN_START>
            <TEMPI_CN_END>
            </TEMPI_CN_END>
        </BAR>
    </BODY>
    <JOBIMAGES NUMBER="0"/>
</JOB>
```

Comment: Yikes that code is some weird mix of XML and plain text processing.

Comment: Why do you need to use Excel to modify XML  files? It is better to use XSLT transformation for that.

Comment: This may help  ...  https://davetallett26.github.io/parsexml.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select node with XPATH.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub EditXML()

    Dim XMLDOC As Object, node As Object
    Dim sourcefile As String, newfile As String
    
    sourcefile = "job.xml"
    newfile = "Updated_" & sourcefile
    
    Set XMLDOC = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
    XMLDOC.Load sourcefile
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set node = XMLDOC.SelectNodes("//CUT/NUM")(0)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If node Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Node CUT/NUM not found", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    Else
        node.Text = 123456 ' new value
    End If
    
    XMLDOC.Save newfile
    MsgBox newfile & " saved", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: The code worked perfectly. Obviously, I had to make some changes to make it work the way I want, but your code is the base!! thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Option 1: Your code is close to finish.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub EditXMLFile()
    Dim SourceFile As String
    Dim XMLDoc As Object
    Dim TextToReplace As String
    Dim NewText As String, Tag1 As String, Tag2 As String
    SourceFile = "D:\Temp\data.xml" ' modify as needed
    ' Load the selected XML file
    Set XMLDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
    XMLDoc.async = False
    XMLDoc.Load SourceFile
    ' Define the text to replace and the new text
    Tag1 = "CUT"
    Tag2 = "NUM"
    NewText = "111"
    ' Start the recursive search and replace
    ReplaceTextRecursively XMLDoc, "", Tag1, Tag2, NewText
    ' Save the modified XML file to the destination folder
    XMLDoc.Save "d:\temp\" & "ModifiedXML.xml" ' modify as needed
    ' Clean up
    Set XMLDoc = Nothing
    MsgBox "XML file edited and saved successfully!", vbInformation
End Sub
Sub ReplaceTextRecursively(ByRef Node As Object, ByVal ParentTag As String, _
        ByVal Tag1 As String, ByVal Tag2 As String, ByVal NewText As String)
    Dim ChildNode As Object
    If Node Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Node.HasChildNodes Then
        For Each ChildNode In Node.ChildNodes
            ReplaceTextRecursively ChildNode, Node.BaseName, Tag1, Tag2, NewText
        Next ChildNode
    End If
    If Node.NodeType = 1 Then
        If ParentTag = Tag1 And Node.BaseName = Tag2 Then
            Node.Text = NewText
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

`ReplaceTextRecursively` could be optimized with `SelectNodes`. (
I just realized that `@CDP1802` posted a similar solution earlier.)

```
Sub UpdateNodeValues(ByRef xmlDoc As Object, ByVal Tag1 As String, _
     ByVal Tag2 As String, ByVal NewText As String)
    Dim nodes As Object
    Set nodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//" & Tag1 & "/" & Tag2)
    If Not nodes Is Nothing Then
        For Each node In nodes
            node.Text = NewText
        Next node
    End If
End Sub
```

---

Option 2: Substituting the target tag using `RegExp` is a straightforward method. However, it may not be as reliable as parsing XML when working with complex XML data.

- replace `<CUT>*<NUM>*</NUM>` with `<CUT>*<NUM>88</NUM>`

*Note:* `RegExp` is not the best solution to handle XML/HTML. Please refer to `@Yitzhak Khabinsky`'s comment.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub ReplaceNumInXML()
    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim sText As String
    Dim EndTag As String
    ' modify as needed
    Const PRETAG = "<CUT>"
    Const Tag = "<NUM>"
    Const NEWNUM = 88
    Const FILE_PATH = "D:\Temp\data.xml"
    ' **********
    ' Create ending tage
    EndTag = "</" & Mid(Tag, 2)
    ' Read xml file
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(FILE_PATH, 1)
    sText = objFile.ReadAll
    objFile.Close
    Dim RegEx As Object
    Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With RegEx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = False
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = "(" & PRETAG & ".*?" & Tag & ")\d+(" & EndTag & ")"
        ' Replace num
        sText = .Replace(sText, "$1" & NEWNUM & EndTag)
    End With
    ' Write result to new xml file
    Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(Replace(FILE_PATH, ".xml", "_new.xml"), True)
    objFile.Write sText
    objFile.Close
    Set objFile = Nothing
    Set objFSO = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't parse XML/HTML with regex, use a proper XML/HTML parser.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49352243/bash-regex-for-html-contents/49352373#49352373

Why it's not possible to use regex to parse HTML/XML: a formal explanation in layman's terms
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la

Comment: hanks for sharing. For complicated XML/HTML, you are right. I would think OP's case fits `you know the structure is consistent`. I added a Note to remind OP.