# Regex to match XML element content ignoring namespace

Tags: regex, xml

Prefacing this by saying I cannot use an XML parser as I am dealing with a logging framework that requires regex as input in its configuration to filter text.

I have an XML element like so

`<ns1:SomeTag>The value</ns1:SomeTag>`

and I would like to match the text inside this tag (`The value`). The problem is, I cannot rely on the namespace prefix being the same in all cases - `ns1` in this case. Other times it might be `ns2`, `xyz` etc.

How would I write a Regex that accounts for this?

I've tried building upon the answers in another question here - [Regex Match all characters between two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109882/regex-match-all-characters-between-two-strings), and I've arrived at `(?<=<\w+SomeTag>)(.*)(?=<\/\w+:SomeTag>)` but there is an error given by [www.regex101.com](http://www.regex101.com) - `A quantifier inside a lookbehind makes it non-fixed width`.

Comment: Matching any word? Tried `\w+` yet?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried your suggestion now like this
`(?<=<\w+SomeTag>)(.*)(?=<\/\w+:SomeTag>)`, but it looks like there is a problem with the first `\w+`: `A quantifier inside a lookbehind makes it non-fixed width` (Given by regex101.com). Removing it seems to make it work but I would like to match the first token too, if possible

Comment: Don't parse XML/HTML with regex, use a proper XML/HTML parser.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49352243/bash-regex-for-html-contents/49352373#49352373

Comment: You should not use `.*`, you need `.*?`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Not sure what you mean, but I tried `.*?` too and the error still persists.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky Unfortunately I am dealing with a logging framework that requires regex as input in its configuration to find specific text.

Comment: You should explain all this in the question. Anyway, it is still a `\w+` question.

Comment: Alright, I've added the info to the question.

Comment: @Sander, considering there is very little details in your question I am providing a suggestion and you can modify to maybe work with your system. The \1 might need to be $1 but you can test both and change ([^>]*) to ([^>]+) if you dont want to match an empty string. This is to point you in the direction ```<(ns1:SomeTag)>([^>]*)<\/\1>```