Modify this regex to select ONLY the immediate surrounding specific tags and not siblings
I'm using Visual Studio Code to run a find/replace on a folder full of XML files.
I need to remove all LineItem nodes with a specific string "S00BBABHK".
NOTE:this code is formatted for clarity, the actual XML in the files I'm working with are one single line and are not formatted in any way.
            <LineItem sequence="0">
                ...
                    <Item id="GOOD_1" />
                ...
            </LineItem>     
            <LineItem sequence="0">
                ...
                    <Item id="GOOD_2" />
                ...
            </LineItem>
            <LineItem sequence="0">
                ...
                    <Item id="S00BBABHK" />
                ...
            </LineItem>
            <LineItem sequence="0">
                ...
                    <Item id="Good3" />
                ...
            </LineItem>     

Here is the contents of an example file. NOTE:The files contain one single line and are not formatted in any way.
<ICSMXML xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.icsm.com/icsmxml"><Header><MsgDelivery><To><Credential><Domain>ICSMID</Domain><Identity>196M</Identity></Credential></To><From><Credential><Domain>ICSMID</Domain><Identity>LVS</Identity></Credential></From><Sender><Credential><Domain>DNS</Domain><Identity>BOSSAPI</Identity></Credential></Sender></MsgDelivery><MsgHeader><MessageId>40cb9826-e2e0-4ca2-8de7-08ab9f601cc4</MessageId><Timestamp>2024-04-10T07:12:52</Timestamp><DocumentId>ICSMPO</DocumentId></MsgHeader><ConversationState><ConversationId>9790f6aa-2225-461b-8c85-cd97e7ee2577</ConversationId></ConversationState></Header><Request deploymentMode="production"><OrderRequest><OrderRequestHeader orderDate="2024-04-09" orderID="SA1403865" type="new" orderType="regular" shippingType="item"><CustomerIdentification><CustomerInfo name="PONumber">33475712</CustomerInfo><CorporateInfo name="AccountNumber">Lovesac</CorporateInfo></CustomerIdentification></OrderRequestHeader><LineItem sequence="0"><CustomerIdentification><CorporateInfo name="unitOfMeasureQty">1</CorporateInfo><CorporateInfo name="unitTransferCost">0.000000</CorporateInfo><CorporateInfo name="SellCode">E</CorporateInfo></CustomerIdentification><LineItemConfiguration /><LineItemShipping domain="ICSM" carrier="P" serviceLevel="PF"><ShipTo><Address><Name>Brianna Eales</Name><PostalAddress addressID=""><DeliverTo>Brianna Eales</DeliverTo><Street>5010 RENO DR</Street><Street /><City>PASADENA</City><State>TX</State><PostalCode>77505-2156</PostalCode><Country>United States</Country></PostalAddress></Address></ShipTo></LineItemShipping><PartnerItemDetail type="point" lineNumber="5" quantity="1" unitOfMeasure="EA"><Item id="S00BBABHK" /><Price valueType="unit"><Money currency="USD">0.000000</Money></Price><Price valueType="extended"><Money currency="USD">0.00</Money></Price></PartnerItemDetail><PartnerItemDetail type="production" lineNumber="5" quantity="1" unitOfMeasure="EA"><Item id="S00BBABHK" /><Price valueType="unit"><Money currency="USD">0.000000</Money></Price><Price valueType="extended"><Money currency="USD">0.00</Money></Price></PartnerItemDetail></LineItem><LineItem sequence="0"><CustomerIdentification><CorporateInfo name="unitOfMeasureQty">1</CorporateInfo><CorporateInfo name="unitTransferCost">0.000000</CorporateInfo><CorporateInfo name="SellCode">E</CorporateInfo></CustomerIdentification><LineItemConfiguration /><LineItemShipping domain="ICSM" carrier="P" serviceLevel="PF"><ShipTo><Address><Name>Brianna Eales</Name><PostalAddress addressID=""><DeliverTo>Brianna Eales</DeliverTo><Street>5010 RENO DR</Street><Street /><City>PASADENA</City><State>TX</State><PostalCode>77505-2156</PostalCode><Country>United States</Country></PostalAddress></Address></ShipTo></LineItemShipping><PartnerItemDetail type="point" lineNumber="6" quantity="1" unitOfMeasure="EA"><Item id="UM6494" /><Price valueType="unit"><Money currency="USD">0.000000</Money></Price><Price valueType="extended"><Money currency="USD">0.00</Money></Price></PartnerItemDetail><PartnerItemDetail type="production" lineNumber="6" quantity="1" unitOfMeasure="EA"><Item id="UM6494" /><Price valueType="unit"><Money currency="USD">0.000000</Money></Price><Price valueType="extended"><Money currency="USD">0.00</Money></Price></PartnerItemDetail></LineItem><LineItem sequence="0"><CustomerIdentification><CorporateInfo name="unitOfMeasureQty">1</CorporateInfo><CorporateInfo name="unitTransferCost">0.000000</CorporateInfo><CorporateInfo name="SellCode">E</CorporateInfo></CustomerIdentification><LineItemConfiguration /><LineItemShipping domain="ICSM" carrier="P" serviceLevel="PF"><ShipTo><Address><Name>Brianna Eales</Name><PostalAddress addressID=""><DeliverTo>Brianna Eales</DeliverTo><Street>5010 RENO DR</Street><Street /><City>PASADENA</City><State>TX</State><PostalCode>77505-2156</PostalCode><Country>United States</Country></PostalAddress></Address></ShipTo></LineItemShipping><PartnerItemDetail type="point" lineNumber="7" quantity="1" unitOfMeasure="EA"><Item id="UM5562" /><Price valueType="unit"><Money currency="USD">0.000000</Money></Price><Price valueType="extended"><Money currency="USD">0.00</Money></Price></PartnerItemDetail><PartnerItemDetail type="production" lineNumber="7" quantity="1" unitOfMeasure="EA"><Item id="UM5562" /><Price valueType="unit"><Money currency="USD">0.000000</Money></Price><Price valueType="extended"><Money currency="USD">0.00</Money></Price></PartnerItemDetail></LineItem><LineItem sequence="0"><CustomerIdentification><CorporateInfo name="unitOfMeasureQty">1</CorporateInfo><CorporateInfo name="unitTransferCost">0.000000</CorporateInfo><CorporateInfo name="SellCode">E</CorporateInfo></CustomerIdentification><LineItemConfiguration /><LineItemShipping domain="ICSM" carrier="P" serviceLevel="PF"><ShipTo><Address><Name>Brianna Eales</Name><PostalAddress addressID=""><DeliverTo>Brianna Eales</DeliverTo><Street>5010 RENO DR</Street><Street /><City>PASADENA</City><State>TX</State><PostalCode>77505-2156</PostalCode><Country>United States</Country></PostalAddress></Address></ShipTo></LineItemShipping><PartnerItemDetail type="point" lineNumber="8" quantity="1" unitOfMeasure="EA"><Item id="UM5467" /><Price valueType="unit"><Money currency="USD">0.000000</Money></Price><Price valueType="extended"><Money currency="USD">0.00</Money></Price></PartnerItemDetail><PartnerItemDetail type="production" lineNumber="8" quantity="1" unitOfMeasure="EA"><Item id="UM5467" /><Price valueType="unit"><Money currency="USD">0.000000</Money></Price><Price valueType="extended"><Money currency="USD">0.00</Money></Price></PartnerItemDetail></LineItem><LineItem sequence="0"><CustomerIdentification><CorporateInfo name="unitOfMeasureQty">1</CorporateInfo><CorporateInfo name="unitTransferCost">0.000000</CorporateInfo><CorporateInfo name="SellCode">E</CorporateInfo></CustomerIdentification><LineItemConfiguration /><LineItemShipping domain="ICSM" carrier="P" serviceLevel="PF"><ShipTo><Address><Name>Brianna Eales</Name><PostalAddress addressID=""><DeliverTo>Brianna Eales</DeliverTo><Street>5010 RENO DR</Street><Street /><City>PASADENA</City><State>TX</State><PostalCode>77505-2156</PostalCode><Country>United States</Country></PostalAddress></Address></ShipTo></LineItemShipping><PartnerItemDetail type="point" lineNumber="9" quantity="1" unitOfMeasure="EA"><Item id="UM3925" /><Price valueType="unit"><Money currency="USD">0.000000</Money></Price><Price valueType="extended"><Money currency="USD">0.00</Money></Price></PartnerItemDetail><PartnerItemDetail type="production" lineNumber="9" quantity="1" unitOfMeasure="EA"><Item id="UM3925" /><Price valueType="unit"><Money currency="USD">0.000000</Money></Price><Price valueType="extended"><Money currency="USD">0.00</Money></Price></PartnerItemDetail></LineItem></OrderRequest></Request></ICSMXML>

I'm using the following regex:
`<LineItem.*?sequence="[^>]*>.*(?=S00BBABHK).*<\/LineItem>`

which selects ALL LineItem nodes in a given file if the query string is found in any of the nodes.
I am stuck on how to modify it to select ONLY the LineItem node that contains the query string.
This is not a part of a script. I'm using the regex as a search/replace query in VS Code. (Mac, OS 12.7.4, Visual Studio Code 1.86.2) I will have a batch of these to modify on a daily basis (until the problem gets fixed by the upstream source).
Thank you, in advance, for your guidance and your patience.

Don't parse XML/HTML with regex, use a proper XML/HTML parser.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49352243/bash-regex-for-html-contents/49352373#49352373
Why it's not possible to use regex to parse HTML/XML: a formal explanation in layman's terms
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la

It is much better to use XSLT for your task.

Thank you for your response.
I don't want to parse the data; as in interpret for use or presentation, analyze or extract. I just want to delete a node. I'm unsure why a simple find/replace (with nothing, in this case) isn't sufficient. I will also look into XSLT.

XML is not regular and REGEX is for "REGULAR EXPRESSION".

You can't delete a node without first parsing the XML to find the nodes. Nodes don't exist in source XML, they only exist in the tree output by a parser. The reason find/replace isn't adequate is explained in the links that @YitzhakKhabinsky supplied.

"Parsing" does not mean interpreting the data or using it for presentation or analyzing or extracting data. (Though you'll find plenty of SO posts by people who don't know that.) Parsing means matching the stream of characters against a grammar and discerning the hierarchical tree structure.

Use a Powershell script that uses Xml Linq
using assembly System.Xml.Linq
$input_filename = 'c:\temp\test.xml'
$output_filename = 'c:\temp\test1.xml'

$doc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($input_filename)
$items = $doc.Descendants('LineItem').Foreach( [System.Xml.Linq.XElement])
$length = $items.Count - 1
for($i = $length; $i -ge 0; $i--)
{
   $item = $items[$i]
   $id = $item.Element('Item').Attribute('id').Value
   if($id -eq 'S00BBABHK') { $item.Remove() }
}
$doc.Save($output_filename)

